# Jitpack cant resolve repo, 401 read access error

Tags: git, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

A day ago I was able to use my library through jitpack just fine.

Here is the line I was using in my `build.gradle` to pull in the dependency:

`compile 'com.github.MyOrg:MyRepo:feature_genre_tabs-SNAPSHOT'`

So this was pulling in a SNAPSHOT from my `feature_genre_tabs` branch.

Yesterday I pushed a new commit, and now when trying to build my project, I get the following:

> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/github/myorg/myrepo/feature_genre_tabs-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>
> Could not GET (https://jitpack.io/com/github/myorg/myrepo/feature_genre_tabs-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml) Received status code 401 from server: No read access to repo.

Why might this be happening? Whats interesting, is if I use an older release (`compile 'com.github.myorg:myrepo:1.4'`) it compiles successfully, so I'm not sure why it would suggest I dont have read access.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the issue was our organization was using a trial version the past 2 weeks and it ran out without notification. Needs a better error message.